# How do thicker airfoils give better stall characteristics?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil, stall

Why do thicker airfoils have better stall characteristics? They make more lift, but I don’t see any reason for them to have better stall characteristics. Also, I heard a rounded airfoil nose will help with this, why is that?

Edit : better stall characteristics meaning that it has a progressive loss of lift and doesn’t loose lift all of the sudden. Also the pitching moment changes smoother.

Comment: Please define what you mean with "*better stall characteristics*"

Comment: @sophit oh I actually forgot to add that part, thanks for reminding me!  Fixed.

Comment: @sophit Also do you know why this question is getting downvoted? I don’t see a problem with it.

Comment: No idea why the downvote, it would be nice to get first a suggestion and then possibly a downvote ‍♂️ In my opinion is a legitimate and interesting aerodynamics question

Comment: @sophit exactly, I wish people would comment when they downvote. I feel like not commenting almost defeats the purpose of downvoting, as you don’t know what to improve.

Comment: "I don't see any reason for them to have better stall characteristics"  Time to do some reading about (subsonic) airflow around a sharp and rounded leading edge surface.  Start with a flat plate and see what one would do with the shape of the leading edge to keep airflow attached as AoA increases.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni That makes sense, thanks. That almost seems like it could be its own answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For airfoils used in GA, "thicker" and "rounder nose" are identical. The thicker it is, the larger the radius of curvature at the nose must be.

A rounder LE will

> increase the range of angles of attack at which the boundary layer stays attached, and allow for a more gradual transition between normal flow and stall

by reducing the pressure gradient that tries to detach the boundary layer from the airfoil.

-- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/58452/31425